# Saving a blob to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blob, multer

so I have a program that grabs the meta data out of the sound file.

If the sound file has an album image I am able to turn that into a blob object url and use it locally, but how would I be able to save that blob image to the server?

Right now I have two file input fields, one to select the sound file and one to select an image if there is none pulled from the sound file.

I am using musicmetadata (https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata) and this is how I pull the image from the sound file.

```
musicmetadata(data, function(err, result){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);

            if(result.picture.length > 0){
                var picture = result.picture[0];
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([picture.data], {'type':'image/' + picture.format}));
                var image = document.getElementById('albumImage');

                imageList.innerHTML = "<p>" + result.title + "." + picture.format + "</p>";

                image.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
                image.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
                image.style.backgroundSize = "155px 131px";

                bgImage = url;
            } else {
                imageList.innerHTML = "<p>No image available in Meta Data<p>";
            }
```

I've tried formData to set and append the blob to the form once its posted, but it just passes as either undefined or the blob url blob:http://localhost:3000/5c9db74b-f4f1-4125-8839-a7604ec1f7f9

I am using express with multer to handle file uploads. I would be fine with adding test conditions that if there is an album image on post, then save it to the file system else just save the file from the file input image field.

here is my post request info for the upload just in case.

```
var manageUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'fileElem', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'imageElem', maxCount: 1 } ]);
app.post('/upload', manageUpload, function(req, res){
    post = new Post();

    User.findOne({ username: req.session.user }, function(err, newUser){
        if(err) console.log(err);

        post.audioFile = req.files['fileElem'][0].filename;

        if(typeof req.files['imageElem'] !== "undefined"){
            post.imageFile = req.files['imageElem'][0].filename;
        }

        post._user = newUser._id;
        post.title = req.body.title;
        post.artist = req.body.artist;
        post.start = req.body.start;
        post.stop = req.body.stop;
        post.genre = req.body.genre;
        post.tags = req.body.tags;

        post.save(function(err, newPost){
            if(err) 
                console.log(err);
            if(newPost){
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So everything works how I want it besides being able to save the blob image directly to a server directory for storing album images.

Any help on solving this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> append [...] to the form once its posted

You can't append to the form once it has been posted. But you can delay submission of the form until all your metadata is fetched.

> I've tried formData to set and append the blob [...], but it just passes either undefined or the blob url

It looks like you were passing your `url` variable to the form and not the blob itself.

This snippet hopefully gives you a hint in the right direction

```js
$('#file-input').on('change', function() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var file = this.files[0];

  musicmetadata(file, function(err, result) {
    var picture = result.picture[0];
    var picBlob = new Blob([picture.data], {
      'type': 'image/' + picture.format
    });

    formData.append('fileElem', file);
    formData.append('imageElem', picBlob);
    
    console.log(formData); // Do whatever you want with the data
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/musicmetadata/2.0.2/musicmetadata.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="file-input" type="file" name="file">
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. I tried to piece the code together, but when I post and looked into the network tab to see what was posted with the form the imageElem is "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" and not image/jpeg like I would want. Any ideas on how to get it to post properly?

Comment: `application/octet-stream` just indicates binary data, you can interpret it in any way you want, also as a jpeg-image.

Comment: yeah it doesn't seem to be working. I have to be missing something. Here is my current code. Maybe I have it pieced together wrong? http://pastebin.com/p2h0jxdX thanks again for helping!

Comment: You use `musicmetadata` to get the cover of the song, right? If yes, why do you have an input element for the image in your html?

Comment: just in case there is no image available in the meta data. so the user can provide one.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to create a gist on github and add comments to where you made some mistakes.

Comment: Thank you schroffl I really appreciate the assistants!

Comment: sigh. yeah it still doesn't seem to work. And im not sure what other information i can give you to help understand the issue. I checked the upload posted data in the network tab and it shows everything populated besides imageElem. here is the code  I have that has everything yours has and I also included the route handling for the post request. http://pastebin.com/0vEtqmkg Im at a loss of how to properly save this. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127501/discussion-between-schroffl-and-0xef2387).